# Stack Apps help center incorrectly states the value of question upvotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, help-center, stackapps

On [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/), a question upvote gives +10 reputation, as opposed to +5 elsewhere on the network. However, this is not what its [Help Center](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-reputation) says:

> #### You gain reputation when:
>
> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I have changed the help center to read as follows:

> #### You gain reputation when:
>
> - question is voted up: +10
> - answer is voted up: +10

This is now live.